# GTK3 reuse CSS state background colors

Tags: python, css, gtk3

I am porting a PyGTK2 app.

This app does things like this:

```
        self.normal_color = editor.style.base [Gtk.STATE_NORMAL]
        self.insensitive_color = editor.style.base [Gtk.STATE_INSENSITIVE]
```

And sets it afterwards:

```
        if editable: self.editor.modify_base (Gtk.STATE_NORMAL, self.normal_color)
        else:        self.editor.modify_base (Gtk.STATE_NORMAL, self.insensitive_color)
```

`self.editor` is a `GtkTextView`. The reason why it does not just set it to `editor.set_sensitive(False)` is because the user programs in the editor and when loading his code the editor must still be selectable and we do not want the text grayed-out.

Here is a MWE of my port using CSS:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('Gdk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

view = Gtk.TextView()
view.set_name('editable')
scroll = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
scroll.add(view)

def button_clicked(button):
    edit = not view.get_editable()
    view.set_name('editable' if edit else 'readonly')
    button.set_label('Load' if edit else 'Edit')
    view.set_editable(edit)

button = Gtk.Button('Load')
button.connect('clicked', button_clicked)

box = Gtk.Box.new(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, 0)
box.pack_start(scroll, True, True, 0)
box.pack_start(button, False, True, 0)

window = Gtk.Window()
window.set_default_size(300, 300)
window.add(box)
window.show_all()
window.connect('delete_event', Gtk.main_quit)

css = Gtk.CssProvider()
css.load_from_path('test.css')
style = Gtk.StyleContext()
style.add_provider_for_screen(Gdk.Screen.get_default(), css,
    Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER)

Gtk.main()
```

And the respective CSS file:

```
#editable {
    background-color: white;
    /*background-color: @normal_bg_color;*/
}

#readonly {
    background-color: @insensitive_bg_color;
}
```

That is, I use CSS names to dynamically change the background colors. I have not found a simpler programatically way since everything seems deprecated.

My problem is that for whatever reason `@normal_bg_color` is not white for GtkTextView which is odd.

I guess `@*_bg_color` are generic colors, and not specific to the widget. Or am I wrong?

I would like to have some `@GtkTextView:normal_bg_color`...

`view.get_style_context().get_background_color()` has been deprecated. Is there any possibility of getting the user's theme colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color you're looking for is probably `@base_color`, for historical reasons. GTK has always had a distinction between "base" colors (for text entry widgets) and "background" colors (for everything else.)

It's not quite documentation, but examples are available on [this page](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-migrating-GtkStyleContext-css.html).