# Python, GTK3, How can I change view of disabled widget to normal view from disabled view?

Tags: python, gtk3, gobject

after I change widget state to disabled. view of widget is changing to disabled view. I don't want to change view of widget only change state of widget. How can I ensure this ?

thanks.

```
btn = Gtk.Button("example")
btn.set_sensitive(False) # this code makes button disabled.
btn.set_view("normal") # I know set_view method does not exist but is there a method like this to change disabled view to normal view.
```

my full code

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk


class TitledEntry(Gtk.VBox):
    def __init__(self, title=None, text=""):
        Gtk.VBox.__init__(self, spacing=2)

        title = Gtk.Label(label=title, halign=Gtk.Align.START)
        self.add(title)

        entry = Gtk.Entry(text=text)
        self.add(entry)

        self.title_label = title
        self.entry = entry

        self.show_all()

class AgeBox(Gtk.HBox):
    def __init__(self, age=0):
        Gtk.HBox.__init__(self, halign=Gtk.Align.START)

        lb = Gtk.Label("Age : ")
        self.add(lb)

        agebutton = Gtk.SpinButton(adjustment=Gtk.Adjustment(age, 0, 1000, 1, 10, 0),
            numeric=True, update_policy=Gtk.SpinButtonUpdatePolicy.IF_VALID)
        agebutton.set_value(age)
        self.add(agebutton)

        self.agebutton = agebutton

class HumanTemp(Gtk.VBox):
    def __init__(self, nick="", age=0, country="", language=""):
        Gtk.VBox.__init__(self, spacing=3, border_width=5, halign=Gtk.Align.CENTER)

        temp_name = Gtk.Label()
        temp_name.set_markup("<span font_weight='bold'>Human</span>")
        self.pack_start(temp_name, False, False, 0)

        nick_box = TitledEntry("Nick", nick)
        self.pack_start(nick_box, False, False, 0)

        age_box = AgeBox(age)
        self.pack_start(age_box, False, False, 0)

        country_box = TitledEntry("Country", country)
        self.pack_start(country_box, False, False, 0)

        language_box = TitledEntry("Language", language)
        self.pack_start(language_box, False, False, 0)

        self.show_all()


class AnimTemp(Gtk.VBox):
    def __init__(self, nick="", age=0, kind="wolf"):
        Gtk.VBox.__init__(self, spacing=3, border_width=5, halign=Gtk.Align.CENTER)

        temp_name = Gtk.Label()
        temp_name.set_markup("<span font_weight='bold'>Animal</span>")
        self.pack_start(temp_name, False, False, 0)

        nick_box = TitledEntry("Nick", nick)
        self.pack_start(nick_box, False, False, 0)

        age_box = AgeBox(age)
        self.pack_start(age_box, False, False, 0)

        kind_box = Gtk.VBox()
        self.pack_start(kind_box, False, False, 0)

        kind_name = Gtk.Label("Kind", halign=Gtk.Align.START)
        kind_box.pack_start(kind_name, False, False, 0)

        box = Gtk.HBox()
        kind_box.pack_start(box, False, False, 0)

        wolf = Gtk.RadioButton("Wolf",group=None)
        box.pack_start(wolf, False, False, 0)

        tiger = Gtk.RadioButton("Tiger", group=wolf)
        box.pack_start(tiger, False, False, 0)

        if kind == "wolf":
            wolf.set_active(True)
        else:
            tiger.set_active(True)

        self.show_all()


class ElfTemp(Gtk.VBox):
    def __init__(self, nick="", age=0, clan="terran", race="night"):
        Gtk.VBox.__init__(self, spacing=3, border_width=5, halign=Gtk.Align.CENTER)

        temp_name = Gtk.Label()
        temp_name.set_markup("<span font_weight='bold'>Elf</span>")
        self.pack_start(temp_name, False, False, 0)

        nick_box = TitledEntry("Nick", nick)
        self.pack_start(nick_box, False, False, 0)

        age_box = AgeBox(age)
        self.pack_start(age_box, False, False, 0)

        clan_box = Gtk.VBox(halign=Gtk.Align.START)
        self.pack_start(clan_box, False, False, 0)

        clan_name = Gtk.Label("Clan", halign=Gtk.Align.START)
        clan_box.pack_start(clan_name, False, False, 0)

        box = Gtk.HBox()
        clan_box.pack_start(box, False, False, 0)

        terran = Gtk.RadioButton("Terran",group=None)
        box.pack_start(terran, False, False, 0)

        vanu = Gtk.RadioButton("Vanu", group=terran)
        box.pack_start(vanu, False, False, 0)

        atlas = Gtk.RadioButton("Atlas", group=terran, halign=Gtk.Align.CENTER)
        clan_box.pack_start(atlas, False, False, 0)

        race_box = Gtk.VBox()
        self.pack_start(race_box, False, False, 0)

        race_name = Gtk.Label("Race", halign=Gtk.Align.START)
        race_box.pack_start(race_name, False, False, 0)

        box = Gtk.HBox()
        race_box.pack_start(box, False, False, 0)

        night = Gtk.RadioButton("Night", group=None)
        box.pack_start(night, False, False, 0)

        blood = Gtk.RadioButton("Blood", group=night)
        box.pack_start(blood, False, False, 0)

        if clan == "terran":
            terran.set_active(True)
        elif clan == "vanu":
            vanu.set_active(True)
        else:
            atlas.set_active(True)

        if race == "night":
            night.set_active(True)
        else:
            blood.set_active(True)

        self.show_all()


class SelectTemplateWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Select a Temlpate")

        self.resize(581, 506)

        scw = Gtk.ScrolledWindow(visible=True)
        self.add(scw)

        flbox = Gtk.FlowBox(min_children_per_line=2, valign=Gtk.Align.START)
        scw.add(flbox)

        keltas = ElfTemp("Keltas", 24, "terran", "blood")
        flbox.add(keltas)

        illidan = ElfTemp("Illidan", 47, "vanu", "night")
        flbox.add(illidan)

        jack = HumanTemp("Jack", 21, "Canada", "English")
        flbox.add(jack)

        santiago = HumanTemp("Santiago", 37, "Spain", "Spanish")
        flbox.add(santiago)

        moon_wolf = AnimTemp("Moon Wolf", 941, "wolf")
        flbox.add(moon_wolf)

        lexar = AnimTemp("Lexar", 438, "tiger")
        flbox.add(lexar)

        flbox.show_all()


win = SelectTemplateWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show()

Gtk.main()
```

I want to no editable `FlowBoxChild` (template) but when I set sensitive to `False`, the view is changing (being bad view). how can I do this without setting sensitive to `False`

[image]

Comment: Could you post a MCVE ?

Comment: @theGtknerd, I edited

Comment: What do you mean by "normal"? Make it sensitive again? For that you would use `btn.set_sensitive(True)`.

Comment: @SvenFestersen, widgets in disabled mode looks different from normal mode and I want to change only view of widgets in disabled mode without changing disable mode.

Comment: They get grayed out when not sensitive but programmatically you can change their properties and eventually set them sensitive again as indicated, with `set_sensitive(True)`.

Comment: anyone can help me ?

Comment: @Nomad: just to make sure I got this right: you want the buttons to look sensitive but not react to clicks? That's very misleading (and probably frustrating) for your users, I recommend not to do that. If you want to do it however, I think you could transfer the style from an active state button to a disabled button. I'm not sure how to do that in detail though. This question might contain some hints: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38158289/gtk3-reuse-css-state-background-colors

Comment: @theGtknerd, I posted full code.

Answer (score 1):

No sure this is what you are after, but a workaround is to pack the button inside an event box and then toggle the `above_child` property to get that desired result. The button will be inhibited from emitting signals when the event box is above the button and will emit signals otherwise.

Here is a simple example:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Hello World")

        self.box = Gtk.Box(spacing=6)
        self.add(self.box)

        self.button1 = Gtk.ToggleButton(label="Sensitive")
        self.button1.connect("clicked", self.on_button1_clicked)
        self.box.pack_start(self.button1, True, True, 0)

        self.evbox = Gtk.EventBox()
        self.button2 = Gtk.Button(label="Goodbye")
        self.button2.connect("clicked", self.on_button2_clicked)
        self.evbox.add(self.button2)
        self.evbox.set_above_child(True)
        self.box.pack_start(self.evbox, True, True, 0)

    def on_button1_clicked(self, widget):
        self.evbox.set_above_child(not self.button1.get_active())

    def on_button2_clicked(self, widget):
        print("Goodbye")

win = MyWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

The **Sensitive** toggle button, will control the button on the right while keeping its appearance even when "not sensitive". In fact you are just controlling the event box property.

Pack the button inside an event box:

```
...
self.evbox = Gtk.EventBox()
self.button2 = Gtk.Button(label="Goodbye")
self.evbox.add(self.button2)
self.evbox.set_above_child(True) # Default is not sensitive
...
```

To be consistent with the toggle button, the default is setting the button as not sensitive, then on the toggle button callback, we change the event box property, which is equivalent to the logical negation of the toggle property of the toggle button:

```
def on_button1_clicked(self, widget):
    self.evbox.set_above_child(not self.button1.get_active())
```

Using this solution, would be as simple as invoking a single method, `set_above_child`, on the button's parent container.

Comment: thanks very much your comment. but I did this a long time ago. yes `EventBox` prevents mouse actions. but I can still click the buttons with pressing `Enter` key and using keyboard, I can do a lot of things in this way. I want exactly buttons that are full insensitive but have normal view.

Comment: @Nomad indeed, keyboard events do work but can be inhibited by not allowing the focus and handling keyboard actions prematurely, but it seems a lot of work to a simple requirement. I'll try to look into it but as others have said, it's not the normal behavior for a button.

Comment: @Nomad I think the only way to do this is by using css classes. Overriding the disabled class but it seems a lot of work to little gain. I've used Gtk Inspector to play with css and indeed managed to change ui properties of the disabled widgets but i would suggest that you use a different approach.